# How to create a dynamic filter based on the primary key of ForeignKey in ListView?

Tags: django

I am relatively new to Django but the main problem I am facing right now is to create a ListView that will display uploaded documents based on the primary key of my ForeignKey.

I have tried several methods of trying to create the filter and read the online documentation on class-based view but it does not seem to have relevant information on how to use the primary key of my ForeignKey in my filter.

These are my models:

```py
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    image = models.ImageField(default = 'default0.jpg', 
upload_to='course_image/')
    description = models.TextField()
    price = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=6)
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    rating = models.IntegerField(default = 0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('post-detail', kwargs={'pk' : self.pk})

class Lesson(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    file = models.FileField(upload_to="lesson/pdf")
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('lesson_upload', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
```

Here is my ListView with the filter that is not working:

```py
class LessonListView(ListView):
    model = Lesson
    template_name = 'store/uploaded_lesson.html'
    context_object_name = 'lesson'

    # def get_queryset(self):
    #   return Lesson.objects.filter(Post__pk=self.Post.pk)

    def get_queryset(self):
        self.post__pk = get_object_or_404(post__pk, 
name=self.kwargs['post__pk'])
        return Lesson.objects.filter(post__pk=self.post__pk)
```

Here is my urls.py:

```py
path('post/<int:pk>/lesson_uploaded/', LessonListView.as_view(), name='lesson_uploaded'),
```

Here is my html:

```html
{% extends "store/base.html" %}
{% block content %}
    <div id="main">
        <table class="table mb-0">
        <thead>
          <tr>          
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>Author</th>
        <th>Download</th>
        <th>Delete</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      {% for lesson in lesson %}
      <tr>
        <td>
            {% if lesson.file %}
                <img src="{{ lesson.file.url }}"  style="width:100px;">
            {% else %}   
            {% endif %}
        </td>
      </tr>
      {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Can you please add your `urls.py` ?

Comment: @wencakisa yep sry just added!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try like this:

In urls, add `post_id` :

```
path('lessons/<int:post_id>/', LessonListView.as_view()),
```

Then update the View to get the `post_id` in `get_queryset` method:

```
class LessonListView(ListView):
    model = Lesson
    template_name = 'store/uploaded_lesson.html'
    context_object_name = 'lesson'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Lesson.objects.filter(post_id=self.kwargs.get('post_id'))
```

Also, please don't name list and item of that list in a for loop same, so update it to:

```
{% for l in lesson %}. // or anything other than lesson
    <tr>
        <td>
            {% if l.file %}
```

Comment: I just tried but it is not displaying anything right now. could it be that my html is not using the right syntax?

Comment: probably, I have update the html code as well. Also, please make sure that you are using proper post id, which has Lessons attached to it. @namespace97

Comment: sry can you elaborate on what do you mean by the use of proper post id which has Lessons attached to it? What should I be looking out for?

Comment: Lets say you have multiple lessons which was created using post object which has an id 1, then you should see lessons related to that post object at path `/lessons/1/`

Comment: i see. When I checked in my admin page, the field for my ForeignKey is left blank, i made a post on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56750615/how-to-save-the-attribute-of-my-foreignkey?noredirect=1#comment100059763_56750615. 
Do you think you can help guide me on this part too?

Comment: Can you please check if you are getting expected output? :)