# How to save the attribute of my ForeignKey?

Tags: django

I am trying to create a view that allows users to upload their documents in my Lessons model. However when documents are uploaded, I am not able to save the instance in which the form is being submitted. When I access the admin page, the field for my ForeignKey is left empty.

This is the views.py for users to submit their documents:

```py
class UploadLessonView(CreateView):
model = Lesson
fields = ['title', 'file']  
template_name = 'store/upload_lesson.html'
success_url = '../'

def form_valid(self, form):
    form.instance.author = self.request.user
    return super(UploadLessonView, self).form_valid(form)
```

This is the models.py for my child model:

```py
class Lesson(models.Model):
title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
file = models.FileField(upload_to="lesson/pdf")
date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)

def __str__(self):
    return self.title

def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('lesson_upload', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
```

For my parent model:

```py
class Post(models.Model):
title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
image = models.ImageField(default = 'default0.jpg', upload_to='course_image/')
description = models.TextField()
price = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=6)
date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
rating = models.IntegerField(default = 0)

def __str__(self):
    return self.title

def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('post-detail', kwargs={'pk' : self.pk})
```

Field for Post is left empty when I submit documents.

Comment: In your form_valid method, you need to access the field as `form.instance.post.author` instead of `form.instance.author`.

Comment: @NalinDobhal when i changed to form.instance.post.author, it gives me this error: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'author'

Comment: because post is empty. You need to set post as well.

Comment: @NalinDobhal the thing is i am uploading the document to the post, and i want to tie this document to the post. I dont get which part of the code I am doing wrongly such that it gives me the error of: RelatedObjectDoesNotExist, since the related object is the post that I have already created. What is it that I could have missed out?

Comment: Just a note, debugging this may have been a bit more simple for you if you set the `post` field to not be null, then you would get errors before anything is submitted into a table and you would never run into **"Field for Post is left empty when I submit documents."**. I say this because you have `post` cascading on delete, meaning the entry will be deleted if the FK is deleted, so in that instance I see no reason to allow the `post` attribute to be null. `post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not setting the `Post` object in `Lesson` with the View. So you can fix it in two ways.

**One** way, is to send it via url, for example:

```
# url
url('lesson/<int:post_id>/create/', UploadLessionView.as_view())
```

And use the value of `post_id` in View:

```
class UploadLessonView(CreateView):
    model = Lesson
    fields = ['title', 'file']  
    template_name = 'store/upload_lesson.html'
    success_url = '../'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=self.kwargs.get('post_id'))
        return super(UploadLessonView, self).form_valid(form)
```

**Two**, you can add `post` in fields:

```
class UploadLessonView(CreateView):
    model = Lesson
    fields = ['title', 'file', 'post']  # <-- Here
    template_name = 'store/upload_lesson.html'
```